# Should I say "another ones" or "another one's"

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Since I'm implying possession should I say another one's and your's?

> The book could either be yours or another ones.

Is it "yours" or "your's" and "another ones" or "another one's"?

Comment: You should supply more context for us to be able to clearly resolve your problem, but I can safely tell you that possessive of ``one`` is ``one's``, **never** ``ones``.

Comment: @David: Yeah, it would be *one's* there. But *someone else's* is probably what you need: *another one's* does not sound right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of the options you present are correct. You should say:

> The book could either be yours or someone else's.

Comment: Now that I think about it, "another ones" would sound incorrect if I played around with the wording a bit. Thanks.

Comment: You *could* say *The book could either be yours or someone else's*, but shouldn't.  Instead say *The book could be yours or another's*, which is natural English, or *The book could either be yours or another's*, if you need to emphasize no other possibilities apply. [The question remains, whether to say *could be either yours...* instead of *could either be yours...*.]

Comment: For what it's worth, RiMMER's sentence sounds a lot better than jwpat's to my ears.